# X server does not respond when Spotify takes focus

Tags: xorg, spotify

I've been having problems running Spotify on Ubuntu 14.04. After having spotify open for a few hours, it will freeze all X windows when I return focus to it. I can still move my cursor and terminal hotkeys work fine (Ctrl+Alt+F1 etc). After rebooting from the terminal it will work fine again, but the problem still persists. Does anyone else have knowledge of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the desktop client under some circumstances. I am pleased to report that it is fixed in the upcoming beta. The new client uses CEF3 (based on chromium) for text input rather than handmade native components.

Sadly, we haven't had time yet to create a Linux distribution package for the beta, but it is coming soon. Keep your eyes on the Spotify community forum for the Linux beta announcement!